# SQL Query, Return date results dbdate - 7 days from selected date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return results from a MYtable where the date selected, in this case 2021-12-06, is less than 7 days away from EndDate

```
SELECT EndDate 
FROM MYtable 
WHERE ('2021-12-06' BETWEEN EndDate AND DATEADD(day, - 7, EndDate))
```

The above code does not work/return results but gives you an idea of where I'm at currently, should i using a  between method to get these results or is there a better way of doing it. Anyway any advice that can be given will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Column EndDate data type?

Comment: MSSQL, EndDate id Datatype = DAte

Comment: SELECT EndDate
FROM     MYtable
WHERE  ('2021-12-06' BETWEEN EndDate AND DATEADD(day, - 7, EndDate))   Sorry copied the wrong query, this is my current version

Comment: Hey, edit your question instead to have the current version.

Comment: You need to understand the BETWEEN X AND Y is logically translated to >= X and <=Y. Do you see the flaw in your usage now?

Answer (score 0):

i think this gonna work for you DATEADD needs day parameter and using BETWEEN is better this way:

```
SELECT enddate 
FROM Mytable
WHERE enddate BETWEEN '2021-12-06' AND DATEADD(day,-7,'2021-12-06');
```

Comment: Hi thanks but this will only return results where the End Date is between Selected date and selected date -7.  What i need is to return the result where the selected date falls between Enddate & Enddate -7 days.

Comment: @DaveHughes This solution will work, just change `-7` to `7`

Comment: SELECT EndDate
FROM     Mytable
WHERE  ('2021-12-06' BETWEEN  DATEADD(day, - 7, EndDate) AND EndDate)  This was the answer i was looking for, i stumbled onto it by mistake, but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EndDate 
FROM Mytable 
WHERE ('2021-12-06' BETWEEN DATEADD(day, - 7, EndDate) AND EndDate)
```